# Suppress indentation in custom environment

Tags: macros, indentation

I have defined a custom `tabular`environment that has a heading for each table. I have managed to get some vertical space between the heading and the table itself. However, the first column of the table is indented. I'd like to get rid of that indentation:

[image: Environment with indented table]

Here's my code:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\setlength{\parindent}{0pt} % This doesn't have the desired effect

\newenvironment{grouping}[1]
{\newcommand{\entry}[3]{##1 - ##2 & ##3 \\}
\textbf{#1}

\vspace{0.20cm}
\begin{tabular}{l@{\hspace{1cm}}l}
}{\end{tabular}}

\begin{document}
\begin{grouping}{Heading}
\entry{A}{B}{First Entry} 
\entry{C}{D}{Second Entry}
\end{grouping}
\end{document}
```

Comment: `\begin{tabular}{@{}l@{\hspace{1cm}}l}`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The “indentation” is due to the padding that's inserted by default at either side of a column in a `tabular`; you can suppress it with `@{}`.

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\newenvironment{grouping}[1]
  {\newcommand{\entry}[3]{##1 -- ##2 & ##3 \\}%
   \noindent\textbf{#1}\\*[2mm]% no page break here!
   \begin{tabular}{@{}l@{\hspace{1cm}}l}}
  {\end{tabular}}

\begin{document}
\begin{grouping}{Heading}
\entry{A}{B}{First Entry} 
\entry{C}{D}{Second Entry}
\end{grouping}
\end{document}
```

[image]